# Why does the nanmean function error when running an example from the documentation?

Tags: matlab, nan, mean

I'm trying to calculate the mean value of a matrix ignoring NaN values with the `nanmean` function in MATLAB. However when I test the code that I copied from the [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmean.html), MATLAB throws an error saying:

> ```
> Error using sum
> Invalid option. Option must be 'double', 'native', 'default', 'omitnan' or 'includenan'.
>
> Error in mean (line 111)
>         m = sum(x, dim, flag, 'omitnan');
>
> Error in nanmean (line 17)
> y = mean(varargin{:},'omitnan');
> ```

This is really confusing. Why should I see an error after using the code from the MATLAB documentation?

The 'official' code which produces this error is listed below:

```
X = reshape(1:30,[2 5 3]);
X([10:12 25]) = NaN
y = nanmean(X,'all')
```

I am using MATLAB version R2017a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'all'` option was introduced in the newest MATLAB release, R2018b. You are using an older version that doesn't have this feature.

Instead, reshape your matrix to a column:

```
y = nanmean(X(:))
```

---

If you have a MATLAB license, you can access documentation for your version of MATLAB here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2017a/matlab/functionlist.html

You can also access the documentation for a function by typing `doc nanmean` in MATLAB. Then you always get to see the documentation corresponding to the version of MATLAB you are using.